# Get the right xpath for my xml

Tags: xml, xpath, webdriver

I have a problem with get the right xpath
I have this xml:

```
<span
 id="X6_5"
 class="FormatTableElementReadonly"
 onblur=" applyToSameControl(this); "
 onclick="handleOnClick(this, event);" 
 onchange="handleOnChange(this, event);" 
 onfocus="handleOnFocus(this, event);" 
 style="" 
 scripttype="text" 
 readonly="readonly" 
 tabindex="" 
 sctype="Text" 
 datatype="string" 
 buttonid="Column4" 
 dvdvar="" 
 ref="var/L.user.array/L.user.array[5]" 
 name="var/L.user.array/L.user.array[5]"
>
 problem
</span>
```

My first guess was `.//*[@id='X6_5']`
this did not really work the way I wanted to because I could see that the only thing that was not randomly created in the xml was the "problem" so it gave me what was on the place `X6_5` :-P... then `.//*[@name='problem']` would have been my guess but that gives me:

> Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[@name, 'problem'] because of the following error:
>
> Error: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Sorry for not being very clear, first time working with this but thank you all for trying.

What I am trying to do is to compair values on the site with an array I have in selenium. For an example my array contains "problem, exp, linker" and on my site there is an list that should contain all this, but sometimes something goes wrong and one of the values is missing. I want to check if this is the case.

The `.//*[@id='X6_5']` is just the place in the list and could be any value that is of no interest. So I need to see if I can find 'problem' in the list. I have tried things like "span[contains'problem']"; aso but with no success. All this is in an Iframe but I am able to press on `.//*[@id='X6_5']` but not able to see the name of the "span" or press on "span[contains'problem']";. Do not know what else I can give you that could help so please if something is missing just say so and I will do what I can to answer.

Anyone of you guess that could help me with the xpath and maybe explain way it is like that sense I am new one this :-)

Comment: that looks a lot like HTML, rather than XML.

Comment: @name is "var/L.user.array/L.user.array[5]" instead of 'problem'. 'Problem' is the text of span element not name attribute value

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. I'm not sure what you mean when you say that *"the only thing that was not randomly created in the xml was the 'problem'"*.

**That said, as you have already deduced, one possible XPath to select this particular element would be:**

```
//span[@id = 'X6_5']
```

**If you really do want to match "problem" (which is this element's value), you could also do this:**

```
//span[. = 'problem']
```

Comment: Yeah, it's the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The error is literally due to the fact that the query itself is not valid XPath at all.

```
.//*[@name, 'problem']
```

What are you intending to do here? Is this an `equals`, `starts with`, `ends with` or `contains` search?

You are probably looking for, to get that query working (working is defined as *not throwing exceptions*, not necessarily matching *any* elements at all) is:

```
//*[@name='problem']
```

You will need to explain more about the issue because it is not clear at all. The HTML you've provided and your *first* XPath query will get that element. If it is not then tell us why, how and what it is doing instead. Explain to me why it is not working.

Comment: In this particular case, `//*[@name='problem']` would not return any results (as the above element's `name` property does not equal `"problem"`).

Comment: Indeed it wouldn't, but he's not explained what he is attempting to do - therefore all you can do, before he clarifies the issue, is get his *current* XPath query to actually work so Selenium won't throw an exception. Once such time exists where the issue is clear and concise, my answer will be either deleted or edited to answer the problem at hand.

Comment: I understand and agree with you. You just might not want to say that `//*[@name='problem']` is what he's "probably looking for".

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid prefixing **.** before Xpath. This is causing the problem. remove **.** and try again.
This is Html not Xml.

Answer (score 0):

To match an element by the text inside it, you don't use an attribute like `@name`, you use the text() function instead:

```
//span[text() = 'Problem']
```

If there is any whitespace within the span text which is causing that to fail, you can strip it with the `normalise-space` function like this:

```
//span[normalize-space(.) = 'Problem']
```